# how to access WordNet hierarchy using JAWS api?

Tags: nlp, ontology, wordnet, jaws-wordnet, semantic-analysis

I am trying to access the top most object in the WordNet hierarchy.

Example: `"Tiger"` must return `"Animal"`, similarly for other things like `"car"` -> `automobile`

I am using `JAWS api` for access to WordNet via JAVA.

1) How to do it?

2) Is there a general tutorial on various things we can do on WordNet via JAVA (JAWS)?

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://lyle.smu.edu/~tspell/jaws/index.html) contains most of the necessary information and there is a number of recipes for different tasks available online. You should at least try something before asking questions, no?